# How initialize dispatcherServlet using WebApplicationInitializer?

Tags: spring-mvc, web, jetty, tomcat7

I have searched some codes for the no-web.xml configuration with WebApplicationInitializer.

These codes are same format.

1. create rootContext
2. create ContextLoaderListener
3. register Listener to servlet

here is the code block

```
    @Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    registerListener(servletContext);
    registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);
}

private void registerListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = createContext(DomainConfiguration.class);
    ContextLoaderListener contextLoaderListener = new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext);
    servletContext.addListener(contextLoaderListener);
    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
}

private void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = createContext(WebMvcContexConfiguration.class);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME,
            new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext createContext(final Class<?>... annotatedClasses) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.register(annotatedClasses);
    return context;
}
```

but, this code is not working. It cannot found the contexted objects in the root context.
So, I have changed some codes, It's working.

Here is working code.

```
    private void registerListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = createContext(DomainConfiguration.class);
    ContextLoaderListener contextLoaderListener = new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext);
    // This is changed code!!
    contextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
}
```

Is it right? I see the first code in spring help doc. but It's not working with jetty 9.

Comment: Which version of jetty-9 are you using? There was an issue fixed (reference: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400312) in jetty-9.0.0.RC3 that would have meant that any listeners added by this kind of code would not have been called. Please try the original code with jetty-9.0.1 release. If it does not work, please raise a bug and include a code sample on the jetty issue tracker here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Jetty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of jetty-9 are you using? There was an issue fixed (reference: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400312) in jetty-9.0.0.RC3 that would have meant that any listeners added by this kind of code would not have been called. Please try the original code with jetty-9.0.1 release. If it does not work, please raise a bug and include a code sample on the jetty issue tracker here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Jetty

Comment: It works. thank you. I used the version 9.0.0 of jetty. thank you Jan.

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem of jetty.
Jetty cannot initialize the rootContext with ContextLoaderListener.

I don't know the reason. But tomcat7 is working now.